# Overlay Button doesn't appear on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, youtube

Live site- http://uposonghar.com/new-video/

If you hover YouTube video on that page you can see 2 sharing buttons appear. That is not working on IE.

That is working perfectly when i put iframe src blank but doesn't work when i put put youtube video link on iframe src. Check this- uposonghar.com/test/ie.html

HTML-

```
<div id="video-container" onmouseover="mouseoverBox1()" onmouseout="mouseoutBox1()">
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-Jkd9GDSyPc" style="border:1px solid #F00;background:#063;" width="600" height="400" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<ul class="share-video-overlay" id="share-video-overlay">
 <li class="facebook" id="facebook"><a class="shareNew" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://uposonghar.com/new-video/" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 600, 400);" data-reveal-id="myModal">Facebook</a></li>
 <li class="twitter" id="twitter"><a class="shareNew" href="http://www.twitter.com/share?&text=Check+this+video&amp;url=http://uposonghar.com/new-video/" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 600, 400);" data-reveal-id="myModal">Tweet</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function mouseoverBox1(){
  var myPara = document.getElementById("share-video-overlay");
  myPara.style.display = "block";
 }
 function mouseoutBox1(){
  var myPara = document.getElementById("share-video-overlay");
  myPara.style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

CSS-

```
#video-container {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
}
#video-container:after {
clear: both;
}
#share-video-overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 150px;
}
.share-video-overlay  li { 
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: I test it with IE 7,8,9

Comment: If I were you I should just use a different css for that specific button only in IE, How to: http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml

Comment: I know how to write css by targeting IE. That is working perfectly when i put iframe src blank but doesn't work when i put put youtube video link on iframe src. Check this- http://uposonghar.com/test/ie.html

Comment: Could it be a Z-index problem with IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `wmode=transparent` parameter to the `iframe` src: [example](http://safaviehhome.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/capture.png)

```
<iframe 
    width="600" 
    height="400" 
    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-Jkd9GDSyPc?wmode=transparent" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```